How can use microsoft Sql server and Firebase in one flutter app
im bulding flutter mobile app using dart and the login needs to be using data from microsoft Sql server and inside the app there is a chat feature that using firebase
(the sql database is already exist in my company system)
how can i manage users and tokens in this case

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

like any other software, flutter is not unique. You should have an api to talk between the app and server, however it is possible to probably find a connection package on pub.dev. do some research before asking a vague question.
